# How to perform group by in python

Tags: python

I am trying to find the average of certain numbers in python

For example:

```
A={('A','B',1):1,('A','B',2):4,('A1','B1',2):5,('A1','B1',1):6}
```

`A` is dictionary and my output should be

```
B={('A','B'):1+4/2,('A1','B1'):11/2)}
```

I got the logic by using some `FOR` loops and `IF` condition but it is too time consuming.

Can anyone tell me a faster way of getting the output.
my logic

```
    for i in A:
            # lis.append(i)
             lis.append((i, A[i]))
             for j in lis:
                if (j[0][0], j[0][1]) not in pro_loc_comb:
                    pro_loc_comb.append((j[0][0], j[0][1]))


B= {}
print pro_loc_comb
for x in pro_loc_comb:
    a = 0
    count = 0
    for j in lis:
        if (x[0] == j[0][0]):
            if (x[1] == j[0][1]):
                count = count + 1
                a = (a + j[1])
    B[(x[0], x[1])] = a / float(count)
print B
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you got the logic, then explain it, so we also know and help you improve the algorithm. Btw, I don't get it.

Comment: Let's be civil and not shout at people trying to help you saddle point, okay?

Comment: then help me if you know the logic bro.

Comment: If you show your solution that you deem "too time consuming" - that'd help because no one wants to introduce a solution that happens to be identical to yours. Also - it might well mean someone can show you how to improve your solution.

Comment: PLEASE DONT SHOUT - we are not deaf. Thank you.

Comment: "faster" than what ? You didn't post your code.

Comment: "then help me if you know the logic bro" so you will stop shouting? let's be reasonable here shall we? everyone who's reading this is actually trying to help by running your codes and **spending their time for your problem**, so be nice and all peace.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't include your solution, I used this:

```
from __future__ import division
A={('A','B',1):1,('A','B',2):4,('A1','B1',2):5,('A1','B1',1):6}
B={}
C={}
for x in A:
    val= A[x]
    y,z,n=x
    if (y,z) in B:
        B[(y,z)]+=val
        C[(y,z)]+=1
    else:
        B[(y,z)]=val
        C[(y,z)]=1
for x in B:
    B[x]=B[x]/C[x]
```

Comment: if this is the same as what you worked out, please let me know.

Comment: thank u for helping me bro, but thats not i wanted,how mamy times the combination of (a,b) repeats you should take that count and divide that count with there sum of key values

Comment: but this gives the result you are asking?, unless you meant a groub by mean, then you missd a parentesis right?

Comment: exactly bro i missed it sorry for that

Comment: @saddlepoint, fix the typo when you can, I don't know if this is faster than what you got, I'm sure it can be done better but nobody got time for that.

Comment: getting a keyerror for ur logic,anyhow i posted my logic once see it and try to upgrade it

Comment: fixed, I deleted a += in the else statement, now it should be fine

Comment: thank you some much for your code,i am having some 35000 combination in my tuple , i will try with your code,is there any inbuilt function in python which can solve this group by  problem

Comment: built-in I don't think so, but if you use pandas library it might work better.

Comment: iam not aware of pandas ,will you plse write it

Comment: check the docs at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/ but you might be more interested in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html